# Can we add an image in a view , in mvc without a model or database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, view

I have one doubt about image display in MVC. 
Can we add an image in a view , without a model or database .
(I tried how to add from database and Model its working )
But I have tried this and its not  working for me,is it a wrong syntax ? i want to use image from some shared folder.

```
<img src="~/Views/Shared/SharedImeges/i1.jpg" /> 
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Views/Shared/SharedImeges/download.jpg")" />
```

Can anyone please help in this.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried?

Comment: That code works for me, are you 100% certain the files exist in that folder?  (I notice Imeges is spelled incorrectly, is it that?)